# Identifying displays

Tags: c#, .net, uniqueidentifier, multiple-monitors

I am trying to identify a screen in a multi-monitor setup to save some data linked to that screen. How can I reliable identify a screen, also after a reboot?

I am aware of the `Screen` class in .Net but `Screen.DeviceName` seems not be consistently pointing to one screen (for example after installing a new graphics driver).

Comment: Do you really expect to be able to change your device drivers and still keep track of a certain screen? The real question is, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, because I am writing a little multi-monitor tool and need to save settings for each screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by getting the DeviceID with the `EnumDisplayDevices` API. Seems to be unique for each screen and does not change after a driver update for example.

WMI is out of the question for me as I tried it before and it only returns one monitor with my multi-monitor setup.

Comment: Some code may have been helpful to others - SO's about give and take, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try WMI instead of WinForms.

The following post shows how to get monitors and their details (s. DisplayDetails
 class e.g.): [Monitor ID and Serial Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270519/monitor-id-and-serial-number)

Edit:

My suggestion:

```
using System.Management;

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");     
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    Console.WriteLine("PNP Device ID: {0}", obj ["PNPDeviceID"]);
```

Comment: I have two monitors and that query returns only one